# Are There Good Methods for Converting Color Image to Gray Scale Image?

Tags: image-processing, color

Converting color image to gray-scale image is often the first step of many image processing tasks. There exists many gray-scale image conversion methods. Most them, however, is to give R G B bands a weighting factor and then the gray-scale image is the weighted sum of R G B bands. I think this is not right in many cases. For example, the most straightforward of way of conversion is to average the R G B bands: gray=0.33*(R+G+B). If we use this formula for generating gray-scale image, then a red object with pixel value R=250 G=0 B=0 will have the same value with a green object (R=0,G=255,B=0). Any ideas of smart color conversion? Thanks.

Comment: That is not the only way to [weight a color image in order to produce a grayscale one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale). The color ambiguity is unavoidable and [often desireable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM1S7sXw-wE) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are method which are called [Contrast Preserving Decolorization](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/leojia/projects/color2gray/index.html).
Those methods are built to keep the contrast in the Color image in the converted image.
They are based on Optimization Problem Solving which creates a Contrast Model in the color space and in the gray scale space.

For instance, have a look on that:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a crucial question. You are evoking the standard linear transformations. There is a rich literature on the topic, you can for instance with:

- Ford and Roberts, 1998: [Colour Space Conversions](http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/coloureq.pdf)
- Poynton, 1997: [Color FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/ColorFAQ.html)
- Poynton, 1997: [Gamma FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/GammaFAQ.html)

Answer (score 1):

The most **standard** method of converting an RGB image into an equivalent gray scale image is to use RGB to YUV transform and get the **luminance** **Y** component which represents the **brightness** of the RGB image. This converison method is used in every commercial image & video processing system.